# Garbage Collection moving referenced Object in memory breaking the reference in Unreal4 Engine?

Tags: c++, memory, reference, garbage-collection, unreal-engine4

Lets say we have these two classes:

```
UCLASS()
class SOME_API ClassA: public UObject
{
public:
  GENERATED_UCLASS_BODY()

};
```

```
class ClassB
{
  ClassA& refA;
};
```

UObjects in Unreal are garbage collected. Do I assume correctly that, if a ClassA Object referenced by refA is moved around in memory by GC, refA will not be updated, and suddenly will reference invalid memory? Does anybody know if the GC in Unreal Eninge 4 can handle this situation?

Comment: how do you expect it to handle the situation? I dont know unreal, but I would expect that they offer some sort of smart pointer that you can use as a reference that takes part in reference counting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GC won't randomly move `ClassA` but if it's UProperty reference count hits 0 then `refA` will be a dangling reference. If you want to have a weak reference to a `UObject` from a non `UObject` then you can use [`TWeakObjectPtr`](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/Core/UObject/TWeakObjectPtr/index.html).

Comment: The part about the dangling reference was clear to me, but none the less it is a usefull bit of information here. 

I was specifically wondering whether the object might be moved, as many GCs move objects around freely as far as I know, to avoid fragmentation in memory.

I am trying to avoid pointers in cases where I also can use references, thus not using TWeakObjectPtr as well

Comment: @lolaldnee Yeah that's understandable, however as far as c++ goes it would be impossible to update a reference to point at an object that's been moved in memory. Imo references are great as parameters but reference members are almost always a mistake ( just an opinion though ). If you want to avoid checking pointers in `if` satements then the best thing to do is to assert their validity, ue4 has the `check` macro for that. Beyond that there should be no performance difference between pointers and references.